# Restore async loop on app relaunch

Tags: c#, multithreading, uwp

I have a UWP app that needs to check for new data (from network) every x seconds. I do this by starting a new `async` thread. The app can be minimized or even navigated from in Windows Phone, and this suspends the app.

How do I restore the loop when the user goes back to the app again (it appears to be still open, at the same `Page`)? This can be done either by re-navigating to the `Page` in question on relaunch or by *restoring* the loop. What's the easiest way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Generally when your app is suspended, if you don't cancel your tasks, the OS will do it. Therefore it's recommended that you will send a suitable signal to your tasks along with saving some progress for resuming operation.

However, in UWP there is something like [*ExtendedExecution*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt590969.aspx) - it should allow your app to run in background up to 10 minutes (as far as I know this is the limit for battery powered devices - not 100% sure about this, and it of course may change on various scenarios).

Nevertheless, I think that checking for changes in few seconds interval may be a bad idea. Maybe you can change the design little and use *BackgroundTasks* which are designed for background processing.

Most of information about app states you will find [at MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/windows/uwp/launch-resume/app-lifecycle).

Comment: Thanks but the question is _how_ to resume the task. I need it to run only when the app is in focus but I need to refresh immediately when focus is restored.

Comment: @Alexej When the task has been cancelled, you cannot resume it. If your app hasn't been suspended, everything should work as it was before loosing focus, part from case where you are doing some job in app leaving/entering background events.

Comment: Can I force a restart of the `Task` no matter what? So every time the app loses focus on desktop and mobile, it re-navigates to the `Page` that has the `Task` launch in its `OnNavigatedTo` method or something.

Comment: @Alexej In UWP you have events like [EnteredBackground](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/windows.applicationmodel.core.coreapplication.enteredbackground) and *LeavingBackground*, possibly you can send cancel signal when entering (just don't forget to cancel also transfers) and start the task anew once leaving bg.